# how to get url of the current tab from an iframe inside my extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an extension that contains it inside an `iframe`, I want to get the `url` of the current tab and populate by it a field in my `iframe`.
How can do this?

### edit

this is a portion of code from the extension:

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <iframe src="http://localhost:8888/portal/extension/" frameborder="0" width="500px" height="500px">
                <input type="text"/>
                <script src="my-script"></script>
            </iframe>
        </div>
        <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @wOxxOm but I cant use it from my script that inside my iframe

Comment: @wOxxOm when click on the extension icon a popup will load, this popup contains my iframe that by it self contains a form that have multiple field, I want the fill one field by the url of the current tab

Comment: In popup.js use the standard chrome.tabs.query, then use iframeElement.contentWindow.postMessage, and in iframe script use window.addEventListener('message', .......), see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/postMessage).

Comment: @wOxxOm can't use `iframeElement.contentWindow.postMessage` from popup.js it returns `undefined`

Comment: Because you need to define iframeElement, obviously. For example iframeElement = document.querySelector('iframe'). You'll have to figure out such trivial details yourself.

Comment: @wOxxOm I know this before you told me, I  get the iframe by using `getElementsByTagName`  but when I use `.contentWindow`  I got `undefined`.

Comment: Ah, you need to put that code inside iframeElement.onload = function() { .... }